# Cycle in biconnected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose a graph is [biconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_graph) and has more than two vertices. Is it true that any two vertices must lie on a cycle?

My idea is: the property of being connected implies that any two vertices $a,b$ must be connected by some path. Moreover, if we remove $a$ or $b$, the graph remains connected. But I'm not sure if it implies that $a,b$ must lie on a cycle.

Comment: Although this is the same Question as previously asked (see the duplicate target), neither of these has a rigorous solution.  The Answer given at the duplicate target is better than the one here only by leaving a crucial aspect of the proof to the Reader.  I will vote to close as duplicate, but I'll propose a bounty on the other Question to get a canonical solution (unless I can find another Question that already has such an Answer).

Answer (score 0):

As a biconnected graph is also connected, there is a path that connects two vertices A and B going through some (possibly empty) set, C, of vertices {C1, C2, C3, C4...}. From the definition of a biconnected graph, if we delete any vertex in our set C there must still be a path between A and B, hence there must be another path D, {D1, D2, D3, D4...} that does not contain any of the vertices in C (as if it did, we could delete this vertex and have no paths between A and B). Hence A and B must lie on a cycle.

Comment: What if there were two intersecting paths $D,D'$ that intersected $C$ at different vertices?

Comment: @Shubham You're right... I think one may be able to ammend it to account for this though?